# Is there a way to import Angular components from HTML into TypeScript files?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Is it possible to import components directly from HTML templates into their corresponding TypeScript files? I was attempting to migrate an Ionic PWA project to standalone components and used `ng generate u/angular/core:standalone`, but I'm now left with numerous missing Ionic components.

Edit:
I'm trying to upgrade an Angular 14 project to version 17 and want to use standalone components. However, only some portions of the Angular project were converted, leaving many missing imports. So, I am looking for an automated solution to fix all these missing imports.

For example, when using the `<ion-header>` tag in an HTML file, automatically add import for IonHeader in the component.ts file, may be using some vs code extensions.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46661

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/standalone-migration